# how to create filter of list <li> using angularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I find difficulties by realizing this filter knowing that I  have did  it by using  Jquery. now I have to realize it by using AgularJS.

See my code here: http://plnkr.co/edit/AN8yJnr4th5vFR4Gdq4i?p=preview

I have a  list(tree) of li:
for example if i search a li , i must show all parents and hide all li the same level.

Any solutions to this approach?

Best regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I put together a demo of how I would do this, you can [view it here](http://plnkr.co/edit/H0dDlr?p=preview).

There are a few key differences to your code.

- The data is stored in an array of nested objects.
- The filtering is done using an angular filter
- The tree is rendered using a directive (I got this from someone else's posting a while ago but I can't remember where.. if anyone recognises it let me know and I will credit you)